# Horizontal partitioning in Hibernate with Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am horizontally partitioning my database, with a custom logic to choose the partition. I want to configure this with Hibernate+Spring. I was looking through some existing approaches for this, and found HibernateShards. But, this one seems or on the way to deprecate. Are there any such similar frameworks, readily available, where I can plug in my logic and database configurations and make it work.

--
Thanks,
B. Teja.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I implemented it myself, using custom configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by partition you are meaning multiple databases and not partitioning a table across multiple tables. One way I can think of is to define multiple data sources which point to different database sitting in different partition. If the databases are also dynamically created then the data sources need to be made programmatically, otherwise they can be defined statically in configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has the **AbstractRoutingDataSource** that allows to dynamically choose a datasource based on a some lookup key. This might suit your needs.

Here is the [very good article](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) about that.